# Creating a scrolling website

Tags: html

Tyler Perry has a web site,  www.tylerperry.com, that as you scroll down different pages appear.  Each page has links to other info within his website.  My question is how is this done.  Not quite sure how to re-create this.  It is almost in a since like the web pages become the navigation bar and when you get to the page you want you can click the links to go deeper in to the website.  I would love to do this on my web page.  Any ideas would be great.

Comment: Just a note - from a design perspective www.tylerperry.com is pretty harsh on the eyes. If a user tries to scroll vertically (and fast-ish) the content scrolls at a different pace from the background images, which makes the site hard to follow and introduces cognitive dissonance.

Comment: that is only the case in Chrome from what I can tell. However I agree with you, initially I completely missed the fact that you were supposed to scroll down. I think it's a great concept but horrible from a user experience point of view.

Answer (score 0):

It's done with HTML5 using the `<section>` element. That's how the pages are defined. The styling is rather straight forward, you can keep your text in a relative format `em` or `%` to make sure they size according to browser. For the images there are css 3 ways of handling those as well.

Basically they have used HTML5 and CSS3, view it in an older browser and the site will be very different.

Comment: Thanks Ali.  another question for you.  I have been using web builder apps like NetObjects Fusion 11, Xara Web Designer 6 to build my websites.  I have a basic knowledge of html,css, javascript, actionscript 3.0 but in order to become a web designer like yourself what web design technologies would you recommend I get a good foundation in?  My mom use to say I’m a “Jack of all trades, Master of none”  well I want to be a Master in web design.  Thanks  Md

Comment: Like me? Dude I have zero aesthetic sense, I'm a java developer by profession and have a lot of front-end development experience which is why I can answer your question. I know "how" to do things but zero aesthetic sense. This is a question you should ask on [StackExchange User Experience site](http://ux.stackexchange.com/). UX is the big thing as far as webpage layout and design is concerned these days, perhaps the answer is already there. Check it out.